# Vbscript msxml12.XMLHTTP error handling

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I use this vbscript code, to download web page:

```
Dim oXML
Set oXML = CreateObject("msxm12.XMLHTTP")
oXML.Open "GET", "mysite.com", False
oXML.Send
```

If there is no such web site, I get an error `80004005, Unspecified error at line "oXML.Open ..."`

How can I handle this error in vbscript? I want to catch this error and show msgbox with my error, i.e. web page is not available.

Comment: OK, msxml2, not 12 it was just a typo... this script runs OK, when the web page exists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are at least three possible points of failure in your script.

1. CreateObject may fail; e.g. if you use msxml12 (digit 1) instead of msxml2 (letter l). Such blunders should be fixed during development.
2. .Open may fail; e.g. if you use "mysite.com" instead of a syntactically correct URL. If you get the URL at runtime, a 'look before you jump' check is advisable, an OERN can be used to catch bad URLs not found by your validation.
3. .Send may fail; e.g. if the site is down or abandoned. This is a clear case for an OERN.

The most important rule wrt **OERN: Keep it local and short** (Only one risky line between OERN and OEG0).

Demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim sUrl
For Each sUrl In Split("http://stackoverflow.com http://pipapo.org mysite.com")
    Dim oXML, aErr
'   Set oXML = CreateObject("msxm12.XMLHTTP")
    Set oXML = CreateObject("msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
   On Error Resume Next
    oXML.Open "GET", sUrl, False
    aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
   On Error GoTo 0
    If 0 = aErr(0) Then
      On Error Resume Next
       oXML.Send
       aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
      On Error GoTo 0
       Select Case True
         Case 0 <> aErr(0)
           WScript.Echo "send failed:", aErr(0), aErr(1)
         Case 200 = oXML.status
           WScript.Echo sUrl, oXML.status, oXML.statusText
         Case Else
           WScript.Echo "further work needed:"
           WScript.Echo sUrl, oXML.status, oXML.statusText
       End Select
    Else
       WScript.Echo "open failed:", aErr(0), aErr(1)
    End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 24863986.vbs
http://stackoverflow.com 200 OK
send failed: -2146697211 The system cannot locate the resource specified.

open failed: -2147012890 System error: -2147012890.
```

Comment: msxm12, 12 is a typo error, i didn't copy paste from my script...
problem is with oXml.Open..

Comment: OK. On Error Resume Next
oXML.Open ...
If Err.Number <> 0 Then ....

has solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 2):

But your problem is it's msxml2.http (El 2) not msxm12.http (1 2). Yopur error is because you dd not create the object sucessfully or test the object isn't empty.

The URL has to be 100% correct. Unlike a browser there is no code to fix urls.

The purpose of my program is to get error details.

How I get a correct URL is to type my url in a browser, navigate, and the correct URL is often in the address bar. The other way is to use Properties of a link etc to get the URL.

Also Microsoft.XMLHTTP maps to Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP maps to Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0. Try a later one

Try this way using xmlhttp. Edit the url's etc. If it seems to work comment out the if / end if to dump info even if seeming to work. It's vbscript but vbscript works in vb6.

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2
```

Also see if these other objects work.

```
C:\Users>reg query hkcr /f xmlhttp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0
End of search: 12 match(es) found.
```

Also be aware there is a limit on how many times you can call any particular XMLHTTP object before a lockout occurs. If that happens, and it does when debugging code, just change to a different xmlhttp object