# classic asp using Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 to cross-domain with https have error

Tags: asp-classic

I will send a json data to the other domain with https,but I tried hard and it still not working,i had read many resource but I still can't solve this problem

my code as below,please help

```
Dim oHttp                   
Dim strResult
data="123" 
url="htpps://test.domain/test.asp"
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
oHttp.setOption(2) = 13056
oHttp.open "POST", url, false        '<=line error here code:-2147012890
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
oHttp.send data
```

Comment: Did you read this article? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863986/vbscript-msxml12-xmlhttp-error-handling/24864972](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863986/vbscript-msxml12-xmlhttp-error-handling/24864972)

Comment: Hi Chris,thanks for your reply, I use your code and paste my URL return error code "send failed:-2147221020"

Comment: I solve this problem ,because the target URL not send back data,It's my fault