# When I try to run this VB Script it says "object required" and I cannot find an error

Tags: email, vbscript

```
Dim objMessage
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

objMessage.Subject = "ALARMNO SPOROĆILO Z NADZORNEGA SISTEMA"
objMessage.From = "someemail@hotmail.com"
objMessage.To = "toemail@hotmail.com"
objMessage.HTMLBody = "Zdravo"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "someemail@gmail"

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "00000000000000"


objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

REM Now send the message

On error Resume Next
Obj.Message.Send

IF err.Number <> 0 Then

MsgBox Err.Description,16,"Error sending Mail "
Else
MsgBox " Message sent "
END IF
```

I wrote this code in Notepad++ and saved it as a `.vbs` file and try to run it, but I get "object required" error. I cannot find the problem.

Comment: You have to turn on unsecure apps setting in GMail options.

Comment: Hello Mark ....thank you for answering. I already did that ...but it still doesnt work, if you have any other suggestions i would be grateful.

Comment: Has GMail sent you an email that you have to click a link in? See my answer here about asking Windows why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863986/vbscript-msxml12-xmlhttp-error-handling

Comment: Yes gmail works perfectly...i confirmed it with the script i posted below..it works. It just dont want to work with the script written above and idk why. I am grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Create the objects require for sending email using CDO
Set objMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set objFlds = objConf.Fields

'Set various parameters and properties of CDO object
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'cdoSendUsingPort
'your smtp server domain or IP address goes here such as smtp.yourdomain.com
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
'uncomment next three lines if you need to use SMTP Authorization
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "email@gmail.com"
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'cdoBasic
objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
objFlds.Update
objMail.Configuration = objConf
objMail.From = "email@gmail.com"
objMail.To = "email@hotmail.com"
objMail.Subject = "Put your email's subject line here"
objMail.TextBody = "Your email body content goes here"
objMail.Send

'Set all objects to nothing after sending the email
Set objFlds = Nothing
Set objConf = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
```

With little more search i found this on the internet...and it works so if anybody else needs a solution here it is ...also if there is somebody who could explain me where i went wrong in my own script...i would be grateful.

Comment: `Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")` you didn't have this line.

Comment: Yup figured it out myself too.....thank you for your time anyways....damn most of people on this website are so strict ....and down vote everything xD ......thank you....

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your original script failed because you had

```
Obj.Message.Send
```

... instead of

```
objMessage.Send
```